# Is getBoundingClientRect().left returning a wrong value?

Tags: javascript, css

I want to position a div ".indicator" just where a li element starts, so
for example, if I want to position the div in relation to the
second li, I do:

```
indicator.style.left = li[1].getBoundingClientRect().left+"px";
```

This is my code:

```js
var li = document.querySelectorAll(".ulcontainer > li");

var indicator = document.querySelector(".indicator");

indicator.style.left = li[1].getBoundingClientRect().left+"px";
```

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
.ulcontainer {
    white-space: nowrap;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
}
.ulcontainer li {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid;
    padding: 0 20px;
}

.indicator {
    background-color: red;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<ul class="ulcontainer">
    <li>OPTION 1</li><li>OPTION 2</li><li>OPTION 3</li>
</ul>
<div class="indicator">indicator</div>
```

The problem is that the div getBoundingClientRect().left is not returning
the correct value for the li elements.
If you run the example, you will see that ".indicator" is not starting
in the beggining of the current li.

Why is not getBoundingClientRect().left returning the current value?

Comment: I think it may have something to do with your CSS style `display: inline-block;`  and/or `position: relative;`. Try messing around with those and tell me if that did anything.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`.indicator` has *relative* positioning.  So any offset will be relative to its default position, *not* relative to the browser window.  (To contrast, *fixed* position is *nearly always* relative to the browser window, and *absolute* position is relative to the nearest-positioned ancestor – which is often the browser window.)

Since `.indicator` is a block-level element, and its immediate parent is the document body, its default left position is equal to the left margin of the document body.

Set body margin to 0, and it will line up:

```js
var li = document.querySelectorAll(".ulcontainer > li");

var indicator = document.querySelector(".indicator");

indicator.style.left = li[1].getBoundingClientRect().left+"px";
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
.ulcontainer {
    white-space: nowrap;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
}
.ulcontainer li {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid;
    padding: 0 20px;
}

.indicator {
    background-color: red;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<ul class="ulcontainer">
    <li>OPTION 1</li><li>OPTION 2</li><li>OPTION 3</li>
</ul>
<div class="indicator">indicator</div>
```

Comment: Why some CSS elements has default margin?) It's hurt. There are also table elements contains default margin.